# CSS - Fixed percent size

Tags: html, css

In CSS, if I set the width of an element to 50% for example, it will change when I resize the page, not in percent, but in pixels.

Is there any way to set an elements width to a certain percent of the page, but ensure that it won't change when the page is resized?

Comment: Which size? Width or height?

Comment: @StanimirStoyanov Width

Comment: So you're looking for a "50% of something, but only at the first try"? I don't think that's possible with pure CSS. JS could do that easily though.

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus In JS that's just window.onload = function() {el.style.width = window.innerWidth * 0.5}, but I want to do it in CSS?

Comment: I'd love to know why would you do that?

Comment: @cyborg86pl Because I want my page to look pretty xD

Comment: i think the size is translated to pixels you see in developer tool - is result of percent value you specified

Comment: You can't do that in CSS alone. only possible way without javascript would be to use media queries to detect window size and then use a fixed pixel width in each CSS file.

Comment: @wf4 I tried like calc(50%) but it didn't work, isn't there any "hack" using the CSS3 calc you can do it? Or with transform?

Comment: I'm afraid not, unless you have a fixed width somewhere then `calc` will always be based on a percentage width (the max page size).

Comment: @wf4 Maybe calc(50% + 0px)... idk

Comment: but that would still be 50% of the parent, which would expand along with the page. I'm afraid that simple 1 line of javascript may be the best way to achieve what you are looking for. Also, that is less work in a browser than using CSS `calc` (which is also not fully supported)

Comment: @Murplyx I don't know what exactly you're looking for. Please update the question with a meaningful/enough code.

Answer (score 0):

Only with CSS you're able to just use fixed container size, and inner elements with percentages.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
}
.innerDiv {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="innerDiv">
    Div 1
  </div>
  <div class="innerDiv">
    Div 2
  </div>
</div>
```

In case that you need %-tage of the user's screen, then you'll need to use JavaScript to fetch the actual size and then modify the container's size. Here is an example for that too:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container').width($(window).width());
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
}
.innerDiv {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="innerDiv">
    Div 1
  </div>
  <div class="innerDiv">
    Div 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `parent container` to `absolute position` like `px`

and inside the container set your layout in `%` value..

Answer (score 0):

It's So simple use media queries for it.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp